# Eclipse Android error when building dx.jar and traceview.bat

Tags: android, eclipse

I know there are a multitude of questions across various forums that touch on this issue but nothing has helped thus far.

I use Eclipse Photon for my IDE.

I installed the Android SDK via Android Studio.

I recently moved to a new machine and since then I get these errors when trying to build the project. Actually, the first image occurs when I first open Eclipse. The second image is what I see when building (I cleaned beforehand).

[image]

[image]

Many solutions suggest reinstalling platform tools/build tools/the entire SDK etc.

So, I did this:

1) Closed down Eclipse
2) Opened Android Studio and went to SDK Manager
3) Unchecked and uninstalled all the options highlighted in the images below.
4) Once uninstalled I restart Android Studio and reinstalled all of them.
5) The errors noted at the start of this post persist.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas what I can try next? It seems every machine move/upgrade causes build issues. It's the main reason I dislike coding for phones, it's not the coding, it's the dev environments!

Comment: Don't use Eclipse. It's been deprecated since 2015. Don't blame the developer environment when you're not even using it.

Comment: Given that Google Play will soon require app update submissions to have a target API of 26 (Android 8.0) you should migrate the project to gradle/Android Studio, as there is nothing to prevent them from raising in the future faster than third-parties care to fix legacy environments.

Comment: Okay, so migrate the Eclipse project to Android Studio and debug from there?